# Disable mouse acceleration in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: mouse-pointer

I did a few quick google searches, and it looks like the most recent [discussion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26176/how-do-i-turn-off-mouse-acceleration) about this was back in 2012.

How might I go about disabling mouse acceleration in Ubuntu 15.10? I tried installing gpointing-device-settings but there were many errors.

I'm looking for a persistent setting.

Comment: This solution to control mouse acceleration in Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 really works:
http://askubuntu.com/a/450672/389523

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following (stolen from [r/linux_gaming](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/3qqoj0/techsupport_weird_mouse_after_update_from_ubuntu/)) seems to work:

```
sudo vim /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-mouse.conf
```

and paste inside this:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "mouse"
    MatchIsPointer "on"
    Option "AccelerationProfile" "-1"
    Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
EndSection
```

Comment: Great, thanks! It works perfectly. I never thought to check r/linux_gaming.

Comment: Forcing mouse acceleration with an update and providing no means to disable it is nota good move on Ubuntu's part... Thanks for this.

Comment: Do I need to restart? I'm not sure the acceleration is off.

Comment: Didn't work on 16.04 after restart. Even when adding `Option "AccelSpeed" "-1"` as stated [here](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/please-add-turn-off-mouse-acceleration-button-to-mouse-settings/3408/6)

Comment: Interesting. I updated my machine to 16.04 and the fix carried over.

Answer (score 17):

You can make it nice and simple simply by running:

```
xset m 00
```

Which will completely turn off mouse acceleration.

```
!#/bin/bash
xset m 00
```

Save the file as a `.sh` script - make it executable with `chmod +x filename`, add it as a startup program in the `Startup Applications` program, and you're good to go!

Comment: This is a great example of how to add startup scripts. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

There is a GUI for this, [gpointing-device-settings[image: Install Gpointing device settings]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gpointing-device-settings):

```
sudo apt-get install gpointing-device-settings
```

[image: GPointing Device settings dialog]
This program has several features missed in the standard `gnome-mouse-properties` configuration dialog, like advanced touchpad scrolling settings. If all you need is to adjust acceleration settings, use `gnome-mouse-properties` instead.

---

If you seek for CLI way, `xinput` will be to your usage.

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 getting `Package gpointing-device-settings is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source`

Comment: Found a way to install it here: http://askubuntu.com/a/783234/13330

Comment: Mind this is **6 year old** screenshot. 12 Ubuntu releases ago.

Answer (score 4):

I find the pointer acceleration extremely annoying. Even when it's set to "low"

*Edited as the link is dead.*

**Find you input devices**

```
xinput list
```

**List current properties for the relevant *id***

```
xinput list-props <id>
```

**Change the mouse pointer speed** (non persistent)

```
xinput set-prop 'Microsoft Microsoft 3-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM)' 'Device Accel Profile' -1
xinput set-prop 'Microsoft Microsoft 3-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM)' 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' 2
```

Setting Device Accel Constant Deceleration to 1.5 gives a slightly faster mouse.

To make the changes permanent, add the changes to a file and executed them automatically at login. Some options can be added to the x-server config.

More details here: 
https://www.x.org/wiki/Development/Documentation/PointerAcceleration/

Answer (score 3):

install package xserver-xorg-input-libinput:

```
apt-get install -y xserver-xorg-input-libinput
```

and reboot.

Comment: This looks interesting. One of the previous answers fixed my issue, but I might give this a shot.

Comment: +1 It works fine for me, with Ubuntu 15.10 64bit and mouse "MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse" (Wisdomcreate ET 2.4GHz)

Answer (score 1):

Solution found there : https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1734400&s=ca88cf7a66bc549b9b504f155e287f53&p=10995493#post10995493

> use `xinput -h` in terminal for a list of xinput commands
>
> we want: `xinput list` which will display input devices with their
>   device ID in brackets
>
> and then `xinput list-props #` where # is the device name or device ID.
>   this lists configurable device settings and their numerical ID in
>   (brackets)
>
> then use:  `xinput set-prop deviceID settingID value` replacing deviceID
>   and settingID with their corresponding numerical values, and value
>   with the new value you wish to set for the variable. (ie. -1 for
>   AccelProfile)
>
> you can then test this has worked by repeating: `xinput list-props deviceID`

For me it's :

```
xinput set-prop 12 265 -1
```

If it's working, put this command into a script to be executed at each session start.

Comment: I prefer the method of editing the standard config files. Making a script to run at session start seems silly; even if I don't have to reconfigure it manually, why have it reconfigure at all? It should get configured correctly the first time. I guess it ultimately doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

A much better way to do this and one which resists to sleep, hibernation, etc is this:

First run

```
xinput list
```

This will give you a list of devices, which looks like this:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ A4Tech USB Mouse                          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ GASIA USB KB V11                          id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Find you device's name and take note (mine is `A4Tech USB Mouse`).

Create a file in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/` called `99disablemouseaccel`

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/Xsession.d/99disablemouseaccel
```

Paste the following contents inside it:

```
xinput set-prop "A4Tech USB Mouse" "Device Accel Profile" -1 &>/dev/null
xinput set-prop "A4Tech USB Mouse" "Device Accel Velocity Scaling" 1 &>/dev/null
```

Now save it. These commands will be run whenever an X session starts.