# How do I turn off touchpad acceleration?

Tags: gnome, mouse, touchpad

inb4 duplicate: yes there are many similar questions, but they are either about mouse-acceleration in general instead of specifically touchpad related or their answers didn't solve my problem.

I have tried:

- `gnome-tweaks` lets me set the acceleration profile for mouse to "flat", but not for touchpad.
- `dconf-editor` also provides this option for trackballs, but still not for touchpads.
- editing `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-mouse.conf` as proposed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/698961/disable-mouse-acceleration-in-ubuntu-15-10) has no effect
- `xset m 0 0` has no effect

I am using ubuntu 18.04 but I had the same problem on 17.10 as well

Answer (score 1):

We will use [SynapticsTouchpad](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad) and **synclient AccelFactor=0** command to solve it.

1. If you don't have SynapticsTouchpad and synclient command does not work, then install SynapticsTouchpad(If you already got it go to step 2).

   1.1 Open Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T or Super(Win) key => Terminal)

   1.2 Install SynapticTouchpad

   ```
   sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
   ```

   1.3.1 Enable SHMConfig

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf"
   ```

   1.3.2 Paste this into the document and save the document:

   ```
   Section "InputClass"
       Identifier "enable synaptics SHMConfig"
       MatchIsTouchpad "on"
       MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
       Option "SHMConfig" "on"
   EndSection
   ```

   1.3.3 Close the document, reboot your system.
2. Open Terminal and type

   ```
   synclient AccelFactor=0
   ```

Tested in Ubuntu 18.10 a few hours ago. Everything fine.

Comment: Works in Ubuntu 20.04. After that you may want set `synclient MinSpeed=<some value>`. `synclient -l` to show the current values.